# Why downcasting needs typecasting to work?

Tags: c++

Why do we need typecasting when do downcasting?

Suppose, I have a baseclass B and a derived class D. Now I create two instances b, d of B, D respectively. Why d = b is not possible without typecasting, even though d is everything that b has. However the reverse(i.e. b = d) is possible.

```
class B  
{  
    /* body */  
};  
class D : public B  
{  
    /* body */   
};

void f()  
{  
    B b;  
    D d;

    b = d;       /* OK */
    d = b;       /* Not OK */

return;  
}
```

Comment: Note that in the first assignment, `b = d`, the object will be *sliced* to convert it to a `B` instance. This might not be what you'd normally want or expect.

Answer (score 3):

It's logical. Every derived object is base object, hence upcasting is automatic. But every base object is not derived, hence you need to explicitly cast it.

See this simple example:

```
struct Fruit {};    
struct Apple : Fruit {};

Apple apple;
Fruit fruit;
fruit = apple; //ok - automatic - since apple is fruit  (see "object slicing")
apple = fruit; //error - not automatic - since fruit is necessarily apple!
```

See the error and line number:

http://ideone.com/JnLc2

---

However, if you overload `operator=` in the following way,

```
struct Apple : Fruit 
{ 
    Apple & operator = (const Fruit &); 
};
```

Then explicit casting is not needed. You can write

```
apple = fruit; //alright - assignment (not construction)
```

See this : http://ideone.com/IGbFI

Now if you add this:

```
struct Apple : Fruit 
{ 
    Apple(const Fruit &); 
};
```

then you can write

```
Apple apple  = fruit ; //ok - construction ( not assignment)
```

See this : http://ideone.com/muQc0

Comment: But again the Derived object is capable of holding everything that is owned by the Base object unlike up casting where the Base object doesn't have the capability to hold the extra parameters of a Derived object which results into OBJECT SLICING.

Comment: @paper.place : yes, but the rest of the part of derived class remains undefined, because when you write `derived = base`, only the base sub-object of derived can be changed, that might introduce inconsistency, and that is not logical either in terms of Object-ness!

Answer (score 2):

Think of it in terms of items. Say `class B` is a ball and `class D` is a dodgeball. Then for all dodgeballs, they are balls (so for all `class D` they are of `class B`). However, not all balls are dodgeballs, so `class B` is not necessarily `class D`. This is just a quick explanation and doesn't give any real technical reasons - but I hope this helps in understanding!

Regards,
Dennis M.

Comment: This is high level explanation. But what is the internal mechanism that restricts it.

Comment: @paper.plane: View Nawaz's response and Thomas' comment on your original post

Answer (score 0):

'b' is a subset of the functionality of 'd'. When casting 'b' to 'd', you can only access the 'B' members and methods, so this is safe. Casting 'd' to 'b' however, could result in problems as 'D' is a super set of 'B' .

Here's a more relevant example:

```
struct B
{
  int m_variable;
};

struct D: public B
{
  int m_other_variable;
};


void function()
{
   B b;
   D *d;

   d = (D*)&b; //not a safe cast!

   d->m_other_variable = 101; // this isn't inside 'B' but beyond it. What this will //probably do is set the pointer 'd' to 101 but it might not: defined behaviour land!


}
```

An instance of 'D' contains both 'm_variable' and 'm_other_variable' and is at least 8 bytes in size. An instance of 'B', on the other hand, only contains 'm_variable' and is only at least 4 bytes in size.

Comment: Semantics: `D` is a *subset* of `B`, because every `D` is a `B`, but not vice versa. `D`'s *functionality*, however, is a superset of `B`'s functionality.

Comment: Oh, well now you're arguing over semantics :) Point taken though.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this logic:

D is a B.

But B is not necessarily a D.

So there's no guarantee that if you can pass a B type to a D.

D may have other things that aren't implemented in the Base (More methods that are required for D to work, that B just doesn't have).

So when you Downcast, you make C++ consider the memory area of B as a D ... Which might cause runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

Since D derives from B, D has all of B's functionality plus some of its own. Now when you assign an object of type B to D then the resultant object cannot be fully constructed as there is no way to know how to fill in the values for D's functionality.

Consider the following extension of your example -

class B
{
  int memberOfB;
};
class D : public B
{
  int memberOfD;
};

Now D has two members, memberOfB (thru Inheritance) and memberOfD (own member)
When you try d = b, the value of memberOfB can be assigned but there is no way for the compiler to assign any value to memberOfD hence the error.

If you really do want this functionality you will have to overload the assignment operator to handle this scenario.